# What is the best way to combine and infer glmnet model results of all samples in a cohort?

Tags: r, ggplot2, glmnet

I'm trying to combine glmnet model results of all samples in a cohort to get a single cumulative model and plot. I would like to know what is the best way to doing so!

My data looks like (original data is large)

```
SLE28sy_w20_dat3 <- 
structure(list(EE86222ln1 = c(0.00809, 0.00437, 0.00437, 0.00833, 
0.00833, 0.00833), EE86223ln1 = c(0.00357, 0.00212, 0.00303, 
0.00303, 0.00316, 0.00236), EE86224ln1 = c(0.00146, 0.00156, 
0.00172, 0.00126, 0.00165, 0.00134), EE86225ln1 = c(0.00228, 
0.00197, 0.00237, 0.00217, 0.00217, 0.00189), blood_vessel_w20 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), adrenal_gland_w20 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L), bone_element_w20 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), brain_w20 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L))
```

I got glmnet (`lasso`) models of each samples from a cohort by this code,

```
data_long <- 
  LiT32s_w20_dat3 |>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('EE'), 
               names_to = 'EE_variant',
               values_to = 'Y', 
  )



#nest data per EE-variant:

data_nested <- 
  data_long |>
  group_by(EE_variant) |>
  nest(data = -EE_variant)


#compute models per nest:

las_glmnet <- 
  data_nested |>
  rowwise() |>
  ## save the model in list-column
  summarise(the_model = list(glmnet(x = data |> select(-Y) |> data.matrix(),
                                    y = data |> select(Y) |> data.matrix()
  )
  )
```

Now my goal is to combine these outcomes from every sample's model to make a single glmnet plot preferably using ggplot2.

Comment: Do you want a different single (gg)plot than provided in the solution you're refering to? ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/76987260/20513099 ). If so, in what way?

Comment: Close vote rationale: The standard for "best way", i.e a relative ranking of fitness of a method for an unspecified set of methods is going to depend on the scientific domain of interest and whatever prior work has been done on statistical issues that might affect validity, especially those related to multiple comparisons. As such I don't think this is so much a programming question as it is a bioinformatics question in this case. But the same perspective would apply to engineering or sociology data as domains.

Comment: Thanks for your responses; instead of many plots in a single image, I'd like to make a single plot as a cohort of all samples.